# jquery mobile 1.4 margin button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a two problems with jQuery Mobile 1.4
- I do not know how to make the checkbox and label  take 100% of width of the screen
- What is the cause of the right margin of the button "Synchronize?"

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="delAfterSync" id="delAfterSync" />
    <label for="delAfterSync">Supprimer après la synchronisation</label>

    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="" id="sync" data-theme="b" data-icon="refresh">Synchroniser</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VAxAS/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css:

```
.ui-checkbox label {
    width: 100%;
}
.ui-navbar ul, .ui-navbar ul li {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/VAxAS/1/)**